How to use pipe for multi arg function?
Pipe works for single arg fn, but how to use it for fn with multiple args?
This version works but it's really ugly
two_args_fn(a, b) = a + b

1 |> (tmp) -> two_args_fn(tmp, 2) |> println # => 3

Is there a better option, something like
1 |> two_args_fn(2) |> println # => 3

or
1 |> two_args_fn(_, 2) |> println # => 3


One way is to add the package Pipe.jl, explicitly import its macro @pipe, and then prefix your pipeline expression with @pipe.
import Pipe: @pipe

@pipe 1 |> two_args_fn(_, 2) |> println

# 3

